# How do I make a button like the JoinVideoCallButton in Discord?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[JoinVideoCallButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWlEw.gif)

Hi!
I simply wonder if anyone here have any idea how to make such a hover effect that could be used for such double option buttons or navbars etc.

I have the css and html code for it but I have no idea how to make the effect work. Also, I wonder if it is possible without the use of Jquery?

```css
body {
     background-size: 100%;
     margin: 0px;
     background-color: gray;
}
 .joinVideoCallButton-2Pohj0 {
     -ms-flex-align: center;
     -ms-flex-pack: center;
     -webkit-box-align: center;
     -webkit-box-pack: center;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     align-items: center;
     background-color: #43b581;
     border-radius: 3px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     cursor: pointer;
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
     height: 36px;
     justify-content: center;
     overflow: hidden;
     padding: 0 14px;
     position: relative;
}
 .joinVideoCallButton-2Pohj0 .underlay-1LCk7B {
     -webkit-transition: opacity .1s ease;
     background-color: #69c49a;
     border-radius: 3px;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     margin: 2px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     transition: opacity .1s ease;
     width: 50%;
     flex: 1 1 auto;
}
 .joinVideoCallButton-2Pohj0 .inner-1e8n63 {
     cursor: pointer;
     z-index: 1;
     flex: 1 1 auto;
}
 .flex-lFgbSz:first-child, .horizontal-2BEEBe>.flexChild-1KGW5q:first-child {
     margin-left: 0;
}
 .flex-lFgbSz, .horizontal-2BEEBe>.flexChild-1KGW5q {
     margin-left: 10px;
     margin-right: 10px;
}
 .joinVideoCallButton-2Pohj0 .callDivider-_hMb9n {
     background-color: #69c49a;
     height: 20px;
     margin: 0 2px;
     opacity: .6;
     width: 2px;
}
 .joinVideoCallButton-2Pohj0 .icon-3tOP24 {
     height: 16px;
     width: 16px;
}
 .joinVideoCallButton-2Pohj0 .buttonText-1b8lyZ {
     color: #f6f6f7;
     font-size: 14px;
     margin-left: 8px;
     margin-right: 8px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
}
 .wrapper-1XTKlU{
    background-size:cover;
    min-height:100vh;
    overflow:hidden
}
.flexWrapper-1ztpWj{
    height:100vh
}
.flex-3B1Tl4{
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex
}
.alignStart-pnSyE6{
    -ms-flex-align:start;
    -webkit-box-align:start;
    align-items:flex-start
}
.alignEnd-3PVyen{
    -ms-flex-align:end;
    -webkit-box-align:end;
    align-items:flex-end
}
.alignCenter-3VxkQP{
    -ms-flex-align:center;
    -webkit-box-align:center;
    align-items:center
}
.alignStretch-1hwxMa{
    -ms-flex-align:stretch;
    -webkit-box-align:stretch;
    align-items:stretch
}
.alignBaseline-4enZzv{
    -ms-flex-align:baseline;
    -webkit-box-align:baseline;
    align-items:baseline
}
.justifyStart-2yIZo0{
    -ms-flex-pack:start;
    -webkit-box-pack:start;
    justify-content:flex-start
}
.justifyEnd-1ceqOU{
    -ms-flex-pack:end;
    -webkit-box-pack:end;
    justify-content:flex-end
}
.justifyCenter-29N31w{
    -ms-flex-pack:center;
    -webkit-box-pack:center;
    justify-content:center
}
.justifyBetween-1d1Hto{
    -ms-flex-pack:justify;
    -webkit-box-pack:justify;
    justify-content:space-between
}
.horizontal-2VE-Fw>.spacer-2Aeq3k,.horizontalReverse-k5PqxT>.spacer-2Aeq3k,.vertical-3X17r5>.spacer-2Aeq3k{
    min-height:1px
}
.horizontal-2BEEBe>.flex-lFgbSz,.horizontal-2BEEBe>.flexChild-1KGW5q{
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px
}
.horizontal-2BEEBe>.flex-lFgbSz:first-child,.horizontal-2BEEBe>.flexChild-1KGW5q:first-child{
    margin-left:0
}
.horizontal-2BEEBe>.flex-lFgbSz:last-child,.horizontal-2BEEBe>.flexChild-1KGW5q:last-child{
    margin-right:0
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-lFgbSz flex-3B1Tl4 horizontal-2BEEBe horizontal-2VE-Fw flex-3B1Tl4 directionRow-yNbSvJ justifyCenter-29N31w alignStretch-1hwxMa noWrap-v6g9vO private-channel-call-actions" style="">
    <div class="joinVideoCallButton-2Pohj0">
        <div class="underlay-1LCk7B" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateX(31.5781px);"></div>
        <div class="flex-lFgbSz flex-3B1Tl4 horizontal-2BEEBe horizontal-2VE-Fw flex-3B1Tl4 directionRow-yNbSvJ justifyCenter-29N31w alignCenter-3VxkQP noWrap-v6g9vO inner-1e8n63" style="flex: 1 1 auto;">
            <div class="flex-lFgbSz flex-3B1Tl4 horizontal-2BEEBe horizontal-2VE-Fw flex-3B1Tl4 directionRow-yNbSvJ justifyCenter-29N31w alignCenter-3VxkQP noWrap-v6g9vO callButton-205P-D" style="flex: 1 1 auto;"><img class="icon-3tOP24" src="http://discordapp.com/assets/0682cf612d4fed39efb57e0a1bcc8544.svg">
                <div class="buttonText-1b8lyZ">Video</div>
            </div>
            <div class="callDivider-_hMb9n"></div>
            <div class="flex-lFgbSz flex-3B1Tl4 horizontal-2BEEBe horizontal-2VE-Fw flex-3B1Tl4 directionRow-yNbSvJ justifyCenter-29N31w alignCenter-3VxkQP noWrap-v6g9vO callButton-205P-D" style="flex: 1 1 auto;">
                <div class="buttonText-1b8lyZ">Voice</div><img class="icon-3tOP24" src="http://discordapp.com/assets/8b47456a037cc496c55ae8f871274018.svg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Part 1

The idea is fairly simple: you need to add an extra "hover box" element inside the button row, absolute position it, and finally just change the left value of the object according to the position of the cursor:

```js
function relocateHoverBox(e) {
  
  // Get all the needed values
  // (idealy don't use as many variables)
  let hoverBoxEl = e.target.closest(".btn-row").querySelector(".btn-row--hover-box");
  let hoverBoxHalfWidth = hoverBoxEl.clientWidth / 2;
  let containerX = e.target.closest(".btn-row").getBoundingClientRect().left;
  let maxLeft = e.target.closest(".btn-row").clientWidth - hoverBoxEl.clientWidth;
  let newLeftValue = e.pageX - containerX - hoverBoxHalfWidth;
  
  // Apply new left value accordingly
  if (newLeftValue >= 0) {
    if (newLeftValue > maxLeft) {
      hoverBoxEl.style.left = maxLeft + "px";
    }
    else {
      hoverBoxEl.style.left = e.pageX - containerX - hoverBoxHalfWidth + "px";
    }
  }
  else {
    hoverBoxEl.style.left = 0 + "px";
  }  
}

// Set the hover box in the right position as soon as the mouse enters
const mouseoverHandler = function(e) {
  relocateHoverBox(e);
}

// Update the hover box position
const mousemoveHandler = function(e) {
  relocateHoverBox(e);
}

// Reset the hover box position
const mouseleaveHandler = function(e) {
  e.target.closest(".btn-row").querySelector(".btn-row--hover-box").style.left = "";
}

document.getElementsByClassName("btn-row")[0].addEventListener('mousemove', mousemoveHandler);
document.getElementsByClassName("btn-row")[0].addEventListener('mouseenter', mouseoverHandler);
document.getElementsByClassName("btn-row")[0].addEventListener('mouseleave', mouseleaveHandler);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #202225;
}

.btn-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 48px;
  background: #43b581;
  position: relative;
}
.btn-row--hover-box {
  width: 50%;
  height: 44px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.btn-row--hover-box:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}

.btn {
  background: transparent;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
  height: 28px;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-row">
  <div class="btn-row--hover-box"></div>
  <button class="btn">Option 1</button>
  <button class="btn">Option 2</button>
</div>
```

---

### Part 2

> Also, I wonder if it is possible without the use of Jquery?

If by "Jquery" you actually mean the *jQuery library*, then just remember that it is a *library*, which means that it is only a collection of useful scripts written in a programming language, then since you can write your own scripts using that language, **it is possible** to do it without jQuery

If by "Jquery" you mean *Javascript* (the *language* in which jQuery is written), then **it's not possible** to do it without it, since you need it to follow the x-coordinate of the cursor.

Comment: thank you!
it works but I noticed a slight issue with it. it has a tendency to get stuck a bit next to the left end when moving your mouse a little faster. Do you know any way to fix that?

Comment: I solved the left issue adding an extra else that sets the value to 0 when the cursor moves outside the container towards the left.